# curl or file_get_contents needs full url path

Tags: php, curl, dompdf

I use this code to generate a QR Code and display it:

```
<?php 
    $aux = 'qr_img0.50j/php/qr_img.php?';
    $aux .= 'd=Text&';
    $aux .= 'e=H&';
    $aux .= 's=4&';
    $aux .= 't=P';
?>
<img width="250" src="<?php  echo $aux; ?>" />
```

It generates and displays it without problems, 
but I don't want to *display* it, but *load* it into ["dompdf"](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf) (PHP PDF Generator).
I found out, that I can't give dompdf the "$aux" variable ("< img src='$aux' />"). The variable returns the correct string, but dompdf can't display it (Probably due to being a PHP file).
I came up with file_get_contents, but surprisingly, it returned a blank file.

I used:

```
file_put_contents('tempqr.png', file_get_contents($qrc));
```

It is **not** due to wrong permissions, because...

when I typed the **entire** URL path, it 'copied' the file successfully (http://localhost:2180/work/qr_img0.50j/php/qr_img.php?...), but I think  that's not a reliable solution, because of the port and stuff that can change over time. I installed cURL, and the same issue persists: It only displays with the full URL path. I tried fopen to 'read' the image into a buffer, and the buffer remained blank.

Maybe anyone can help me (and other readers), to get those two functions to load the file (maybe without the whole http unreliable thing?).

Or maybe there's another way to generate images from ["qr_img0.50j"](http://www.swetake.com/qrcode/qr_cgi_e.html) without calling php that I didn't know...

Answer (score 0):

Dompdf (as of 0.6.1) will no longer parse PHP in your document. You will need to do that prior to passing the document to Dompdf. Probably the easiest method to do this is to render the image and insert it into the document as a data-uri.

You may have to modify your QR generator to work in this flow if it's not designed for command-line execution. Ideally it would just be a callable function, which is what I presumed for the sample.

With Dompdf 0.7.x:

```
<?php
// require dompdf autoloader, then ...

using Dompdf\Dompdf;

$image = qr_img('Text', 'H', '4', 'P'); // assumine PNG output
$html = '<img width="250" src="data:image/png;base64,' . base64_encode($image) . '" />';

$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream();
?>
```

---

FYI, the same issue applied to `file_get_contents`. It does not parse the PHP of a file. It can only be used to get the file itself.

Regardless of the particular method you use to get a file the results depend on the source. Files retrieved from the local file system will *not* have their PHP parsed. Files retrieved via a web server will.

Comment: Thanks for that, I'll try it, but can you explain me, _why_ `file_get_contents` worked with a full URL, given that this command doesn't parse PHP (but it had)...

Comment: If you provide a full URL then you are actually retrieving the file from the web server. The web server *will* parse the PHP prior to sending you the file...thus you get the image. If you get a file from the local file system the file will not be parsed and you will get the PHP source not the parsed output.

Comment: That makes sense... But from where you got `qr_img('Text', 'H', '4', 'P');`?

Comment: I just made that function up. You'll have to figure out the best way to generate your image since you can't just access the script as-is via `exec`. You'll need to write a function to generate it.